# JCombobox and Switch statements

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, jcombobox

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1
I am trying to make a java desktop application in the form of a hotel registry. In this program I have a series of `JComboBox`'s that let the user enter how many people are staying, the day they are booking etc. I want to make it so when a button is pressed a switch will occur that will check if the boxes are selecte at None, or an actual Item.

My question is. How can I make it so if 1 or more comboboxes have not been entered it displays a message saying what wasn't filled in

This is what I tried but it didnt work.

```
case 1:
    Hotel.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("None");                 
    Out.setText("Missing Hotel Selection");
```

My question is, how could I make this work?

I am new to Java so please explain in terms I would understand.

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have three JComboBox objects named : `hotelSelection` , `noOfPeople` , `dayOfBooking`. So first of all set name for those combobox using following code.we will use it after in switch-case.

```
hotelSelection.setName("Hotel Selection");
noOfPeople.setName("No of people");
dayOfBooking.setName("Day of booking");
```

Now Below method will be called when submit button clicked.

```
private void submitButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     


    // Array of all combobox in that you want to check
    ArrayList<JComboBox> allCombobox = new ArrayList<>();
    allCombobox.add(hotelSelection);
    allCombobox.add(noOfPeople);
    allCombobox.add(dayOfBooking);

    for (JComboBox temp : allCombobox) {

        switch (temp.getSelectedItem().toString()) {

            case "None":
                // If it is "hotel selection" combobox
                if (temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hotel Selection"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Missing Hotel Selection");
                }
                // If it is "no of people" combobox
                else if (temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("No of people"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Missing No of people");
                }
                // If it is "day of booking" combobox
                else if (temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Day of booking"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Missing the Day of booking");
                }

        }
    }

}
```

Hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like...

```
switch (Hotel.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
    case "None":
        break;
    // Other cases
}
```

Take a closer look at [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for more details